# Update installment price on product configuration change Product Page Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I created a template to display the installments price of the product, on the product page. I need to update this price when the user clicks the configurable product option.

I created a preference for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` to create a new `price_type_code` but debugging the product page does not pass through the `getJsonConfig()` method.

I also created a preference for `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options` and debugging the product page also does not go through `_getPriceConfiguration()`.

Where should I enter the values for each configurable product option?

Magento 2.2.3, PHP 7.0.28, Mysql5.6

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a preference for Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable

Thanks